# executar a function mesmo que o input esteja disable - Jquery -javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

queria executar um alert caso o input submit mesmo que o inputs esteja disabled segue o codigo.

```
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12" id="submitCadastro" disabled="">
```

tentei com o evento `click` e com o evento `mouseente` e só ocorre quando o botão do input esta habilitado,gostaria que ele executasse somente quando esteja desocupado

Comment: Quando o botão está desabilitado, o mesmo não executará nenhuma função. Você deve habilitar o botão (removendo o **disabled**) e após disparar a função do clique desabilitar. Porém ainda não entendi a sua pergunta.

Comment: oi @JeanGatto, tenho um formulário e o botão so e abilitado quando a pessoa concorda com os termos ai eu queria colocar um alerte ou uma mensagem falando que ela esqueceu de concordar com os termos para caso ela clique no botão sem concordar com os termos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz uma pequena solução com jQuery para te auxiliar, não é necessário bloquear o botão submeter, segue o código abaixo:

```
    $(function () {

    var $form = $("#ID_FORMULARIO"),
        $ckTermosDeUso = $("#ID_CHECKBOX"),
        $btnSubmeter = $("#ID_BOTAO_SUBMIT");

    // Evento do Click do botão submeter
    $btnSubmeter.on("click", function (e) {

        // Evitando de executar o envio real do formulário.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Verificando se o checkbox foi marcado.
        if ($ckTermosDeUso.is(":checked")) {

            // Bloqueando o botão submeter para evitar vários click's
            $btnSubmeter.attr("disabled", "disabled");

            // Submetendo o formulário.
            $form[0].submit();
            return true;
        }
        else {

            window.alert("Você deve aceitar os termos de uso!");
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```